# How do I get the innerHTML of a part of my page when that inner HTML is generated by a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function `getsWeather` which uses the SimpleWeather framework. That function is as follows:

```
function getsWeather(city, unitMes) {
    $.simpleWeather({
        location: city,
        woeid: '',
        unit: unitMes,

    success: function(weather) {

        // ---- For testing the weather code ----
        //alert(weather.code);
        //alert(weather.currently);
        //alert(weather.forecast[1].code);

        var conditionArr0 = conditionsImage(weather.code);
        var conditionArr1 = conditionsImage(weather.forecast[1].code);
        var conditionArr2 = conditionsImage(weather.forecast[2].code);
        var conditionArr3 = conditionsImage(weather.forecast[3].code);

        loc =   weather.city + ', ' + weather.region;
        html = '<h3>Now</h3><p>'+returnsDate()+'</p><p id="city-reading">' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.region + '</p>';
        html += '<div class="icon ' + conditionArr0[0] + '"></div>';
        html += '<i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i><h2 id="temperature-reading">'+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
        html += '<h6 class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</h6>';

        forecast1 = '<h4>' + weather.forecast[1].day + '</h4>';
        forecast1 += '<div class="icon-sm ' + conditionArr1[0] + '"></div>';
        forecast1 += '<h5>H: ' + weather.forecast[1].high + '</h5>';
        forecast1 += '<h5>L: ' + weather.forecast[1].low + '</h5>';

        forecast2 = '<h4>' + weather.forecast[2].day + '</h4>';
        forecast2 += '<div class="icon-sm ' + conditionArr2[0] + '"></div>';
        forecast2 += '<h5>H: ' + weather.forecast[2].high + '</h5>';
        forecast2 += '<h5>L: ' + weather.forecast[2].low + '</h5>';

        forecast3 = '<h4>' + weather.forecast[3].day + '</h4>';
        forecast3 += '<div class="icon-sm ' + conditionArr3[0] + '"></div>';
        forecast3 += '<h5>H: ' + weather.forecast[3].high + '</h5>';
        forecast3 += '<h5>L: ' + weather.forecast[3].low + '</h5>';

        //$("input[name=locSearch]").val(loc);
        $("#weather").html(html);
        $(".today").css('background-color', conditionArr0[1]);
        $("#1").html(forecast1);
        $("#2").html(forecast2);
        $("#3").html(forecast3);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        loc =   '<h5><button id="search"><i class="fa fa-search" id="search-icon"></i></button></h5>';
        html = '<p>Today</p><p><strong>'+returnsDate()+'</strong></p>';
        html += '<div class="icon ' + ' ' + '"></div>';
        html += '<h2><strong><i class="icon-'+ ' ' +'"></i> '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</strong></h2>';
        html += '<h6 class="currently">'+ ' ' +'</h6>';
        $("#location").html(loc);
        $("#weather").html(html);
        $(".today").css('background-color', conditionArr0[1]);
    }
  });
}
```

I just want to pull the `weather.city` from this function but I don't know how to really do that.

I'm trying to do it with this `var currentLocation = document.getElementById("city-reading").innerHTML;` but that doesn't work and I'm assuming it's because the code hasn't been generated yet for me to pull from? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Try setting a variable outside the scope of the function and assigning it the `weather.city` value in the `success` callback if you're just looking for that information.

Comment: @tokiin that worked brilliantly. I guess I need to learn more about call backs

Comment: The issue you're probably running into is that javascript is asynchronous by design and it's not guaranteed that the javascript for simpleWeather has actually finished running by the time your code is trying to retrieve the newly appended element with the ID of document.getElementById('city-reading').innerHtml;

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without a look at the larger context, but it looks like the function being defined here is a callback for *$.simpleWeather()*, so it sounds like you want to do something with the values returned.  If you're putting the `var currentLocation = document.getElementById("city-reading").innerHTML;` somewhere else, it won't work since it runs immediately, before the callback has been made.

Can you just move whatever you want to do with the **currentLocation** into the body of the current callback?  If not, you could think about defining another callback to run once this one completes, then your code should work.

Comment: @tolkiin helped me out - I was able to assign the weather.city to a variable that was defined outside of the function. But with me not knowing how call backs worked, I wouldn't have been able to do it with out your guys' help! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your variable outside of the function and then setting it inside, like below.  If you want to be able to access from html you could also go old school and store it in a hidden input from within the getsWeather function.

```js
var currentLocation = '';

function getsWeather(city, unitMes) {
    $.simpleWeather({
        location: city,
        woeid: '',
        unit: unitMes,

    success: function(weather) {

        // ---- For testing the weather code ----
        //alert(weather.code);
        //alert(weather.currently);
        //alert(weather.forecast[1].code);

        var conditionArr0 = conditionsImage(weather.code);
        var conditionArr1 = conditionsImage(weather.forecast[1].code);
        var conditionArr2 = conditionsImage(weather.forecast[2].code);
        var conditionArr3 = conditionsImage(weather.forecast[3].code);

        currentLocation = weather.city;
        loc =   weather.city + ', ' + weather.region;
        html = '<h3>Now</h3><p>'+returnsDate()+'</p><p id="city-reading">' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.region + '</p>';
        html += '<div class="icon ' + conditionArr0[0] + '"></div>';
        html += '<i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i><h2 id="temperature-reading">'+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
        html += '<h6 class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</h6>';

        forecast1 = '<h4>' + weather.forecast[1].day + '</h4>';
        forecast1 += '<div class="icon-sm ' + conditionArr1[0] + '"></div>';
        forecast1 += '<h5>H: ' + weather.forecast[1].high + '</h5>';
        forecast1 += '<h5>L: ' + weather.forecast[1].low + '</h5>';

        forecast2 = '<h4>' + weather.forecast[2].day + '</h4>';
        forecast2 += '<div class="icon-sm ' + conditionArr2[0] + '"></div>';
        forecast2 += '<h5>H: ' + weather.forecast[2].high + '</h5>';
        forecast2 += '<h5>L: ' + weather.forecast[2].low + '</h5>';

        forecast3 = '<h4>' + weather.forecast[3].day + '</h4>';
        forecast3 += '<div class="icon-sm ' + conditionArr3[0] + '"></div>';
        forecast3 += '<h5>H: ' + weather.forecast[3].high + '</h5>';
        forecast3 += '<h5>L: ' + weather.forecast[3].low + '</h5>';

        //$("input[name=locSearch]").val(loc);
        $("#weather").html(html);
        $(".today").css('background-color', conditionArr0[1]);
        $("#1").html(forecast1);
        $("#2").html(forecast2);
        $("#3").html(forecast3);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        loc =   '<h5><button id="search"><i class="fa fa-search" id="search-icon"></i></button></h5>';
        html = '<p>Today</p><p><strong>'+returnsDate()+'</strong></p>';
        html += '<div class="icon ' + ' ' + '"></div>';
        html += '<h2><strong><i class="icon-'+ ' ' +'"></i> '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</strong></h2>';
        html += '<h6 class="currently">'+ ' ' +'</h6>';
        $("#location").html(loc);
        $("#weather").html(html);
        $(".today").css('background-color', conditionArr0[1]);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function like the following will get the innerHTML for you once it is available.

inside the function check if you have the element with id `city-reading` yet, if not, set a timeout for 50ms then call yourself again to check if the element is ready. Until you get it, then you can set the innerHTML and call the function you need to continue the function chain.

```js
var currentLocation;
function getCityReading() {
  if (document.getElementById("city-reading")) {
    currentLocation = document.getElementById("city-reading").innerHTML;
    console.log('YES. currentLocation-->'+currentLocation);
    //you got the dynamic content you need, call next function
    nextFunction();
  } else {
    console.log('Not yet...');
    setTimeout(function() {
      getCityReading();
    }, 50);
  }
}
//init
getCityReading();

//add the id after 2 sec, simulate the situation of a dynamically added element.
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('update id now');
  document.getElementsByClassName("test-container")[0].setAttribute("id", "city-reading");
}, 2000);

function nextFunction(){
 console.log("I'm a function place holder, lol");
}
```

```html
<div class="test-container" id="">
  I'm city-reading content.
</div>
```